# Can't add or edit records in form after updating relationship MS Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, relationships

Previously I had a Payment table's Form and a Current Tenant's Table's form. The Payment table was related with the Current Tenant's email address.

Later I realized the Payment table needed to include details of old tenants. So i created an append query to create a table containing details of all the tenants. And I changed the relationship so that the payment table is related to the email address from all tenant's table. Now using the Form, if i try to add a record using the form, it shows "You can't go to the specified record" and if i try to edit the records, it displays "The record set is not updateable". But i can add and edit record using the table. This problem only exists when i try to include the "Name of Tenant", "Tenant's Contact Information" or any other field from the "All Tenant's Table" in the form. How can i fix this?

Note: The email address in All tenant's contains duplicate records due to different Check out and Check in date. Except those, all other records are same.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your tables to show how they are set up.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/24c5kp4/8

Answer (score 0):

When you join multiple tables in Access in order to allow updates across both tables, you need to join using a Primary Key.

Here is a great reference on the subject of [Primary Keys](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Add-or-change-a-tables-primary-key-0dde1a80-d913-4d9b-a1b3-061f24ccd991).

Be sure that your "Current Tenants" table uses email address as a primary key, and then join it to the "Payment Table".  The Payment table should also have a primary key (likely an 'auto number' field).

Comment: But the problem is that the Payment table needs to store information about the Old tenants also... That's why I created the All tenants table...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a way to solve the problem... I edited the relationship so that the All tenant's table is joined with Current tenant's table by Type 3 relationship. And Then joined the All tenant's table with the Payment table... It then solved the problem...